# Использование функции IFNULL в UPDATE

Tags: sql, null, h2, процедуры

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** Имеется таблица `DISHES`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DISHES (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   dish_name VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(256) NOT NULL, 
   picture_name VARCHAR(256), 
   unit VARCHAR(256), 
   price DECIMAL(64,32) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(price >= 0), 
   calories DECIMAL(64,32) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(calories >= 0), 
   UNIQUE(dish_name)
);
```

И представление `DISH_PRICE_CALORIES`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
    (dish_id, price, calories) AS 
    SELECT 
    DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id, 
    SUM(PRODUCTS.price * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product),
    SUM(PRODUCTS.calories * DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.amount_product)
    FROM 
    DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION, PRODUCTS 
    WHERE DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.product_id = PRODUCTS.id 
    GROUP BY DISH_TO_PRODUCTS_COMPOSITION.dish_id;
```

Необходимо обновить столбцы `price` и `calories` в таблице `DISHES` для блюда с заданным `id`, используя данные из представления. Нужно учитывать, что возможна ситуация, когда представление `DISH_PRICE_CALORIES` не будет содержать строки для блюда с заданным `id`.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:** я пробовал следующие запросы:

```sql
UPDATE DISHES 
    SET(price, calories) = 
       (SELECT IFNULL(DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price,0), 
               IFNULL(DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories,0)  
        FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
        WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id) 
    WHERE DISHES.id = 115;
```

```sql
UPDATE DISHES 
   SET(price, calories) = 
       CASEWHEN( 
          EXISTS(
             SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price, DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories 
             FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
             WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id 
          ), 
          (SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price, DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories 
           FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
           WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id), 
           0 
       )
    WHERE DISHES.id = 115;
```

```sql
UPDATE DISHES 
   SET(price, calories) = 
       IFNULL((SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price,
                      DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories  
               FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
               WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id),0) 
    WHERE DISHES.id = 115;
```

(Число `115` я привел здесь просто для примера. Число может быть любым.)

Каждый из них выполняется, но колонки `price` и `calories` таблицы `DISHES` все равно содержат значения `NULL`.

**Вопрос:** как мне поместить значение `0` в колонки `price` и `calories` таблицы `DISHES` в случае, если в представлении `DISH_PRICE_CALORIES` нет строки для блюда с заданным ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выше, Герман Борисов дал почти верный ответ. Проблема действительно была в том, что я пытался передать в IFNULL строку, а не выражение. Но представленный им запрос содержал несколько синтаксических ошибок. Исправив их я получил:

```
UPDATE DISHES 
   SET price = 
       IFNULL(SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price 
              FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
              WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id,0), 
       calories = 
       IFNULL(SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories 
              FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
              WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id,0) 
WHERE DISHES.id = 115;
```

(Повторюсь, что число 115 я привел здесь просто для примера. Число может быть любым.)

Answer (score 1):

Не специалист по H2, но мне кажется, что проблема в том, что в IFNULL вы пытаетесь передать строку, а не выражение.

Вроде бы должно быть как-то так:

```
UPDATE DISHES 
   SET(price, calories) = 
      (IFNULL((SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.price,
               FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
               WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id),0),
       IFNULL((SELECT DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.calories,
               FROM DISH_PRICE_CALORIES 
               WHERE DISH_PRICE_CALORIES.dish_id = DISHES.id),0))
   WHERE DISHES.id = 115;
```